# Show that there is only one $G$-invariant inner product (up to scalar multiplication) on an irreducible representation by using an intertwining map.

Tags: representation-theory

I want to solve the following exercise.

Let $G$ be a finite group and $V$ a finite dimensional vector space. Let $(V, \pi_V)$ be a representation of $G$ equipped with two invariant inner
products $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle_1$ and $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle_2$ . Show that there is an intertwining map $\Phi : V \rightarrow V$
such that $\langle \Phi(u) , v \rangle_1 = \langle u , v \rangle_2$ for all $u, v \in V.$ Deduce that if $V$ is irreducible, then the invariant scalar product is unique up to multiplication by a non-zero constant.

The last part is easy to do using Schur's Lemma (and assuming the first part). It's the first part I'm having trouble with. I can't even begin to figure out what $\Phi$ is supposed to be. I'd be grateful for any help/hints, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a fixed $u\in V$, the map $f(v):=\langle u,v\rangle_2$ is a linear functional, and as such there's a unique vector $w\in V$ such that
$f(v)=\langle w,v\rangle_1$.
(To see this, fix an $\langle,\rangle_1$-orthonormal basis $e_1,\dots,e_n$, then the $i$th coordinate of such a $w$ must be $\langle w,e_i\rangle_1=f(e_i)$, and then set $w=\sum_i f(e_i)\,e_i$.)

Call $\Phi(u):=w$, this is thus a well defined map. It's easy to see that it's linear, and it's intertwining because for all $g\in G,\, u,v\in V$ we have
$$\langle\Phi(gu),\,gv\rangle_1\ =\ \langle gu,\,gv\rangle_2\ =\ \langle u,v\rangle_2\ =\ \langle\Phi(u),v\rangle_1=\langle g\,\Phi(u),\,gv\rangle_1\,.$$
When $u$ and $g$ is fixed, this holds for all $v$, so in particular it holds for each $g^{-1}e_i$ showing that the $i$th coordinate of $\Phi(gu)$ and $g\,\Phi(u)$ coincide.

Comment: Thank you! You mean that $f$ is antilinear right? If this is the case I think everything checks out from there on without modification